# PUBNUB: on "PUBNUB.subscribe", window.print() not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, real-time-updates, pubnub

In one of my app am using PUBNUB for real-time web communication.

But am facing some weird problem as when i subscribe some channels then **`window.print()`** (print preview dialog not opening) is not working at all.

& if i do the Unsubscribe the channel the printing working fine.

Even i tried this on [PubNub Console](http://www.pubnub.com/console) also. This might be a bug at pubnub side.

Any one of us facing the same issue & got resolved it then please guide me on this.

**NOTE:** I am using this on chrome's latest version.

Comment: Yes, i tried this on Pubnub's console, its not working at all,
PUBNUB team pl look into it. its serious problem.

Comment: Make sure to contact PubNub Support team as they are very responsive and get back to you quickly.  Since you are violating security by signaling remotely to print, this of course will not be a good idea.  However this is a duplicate thread and the solution is here - https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/issues/204#issuecomment-15909160

Comment: @PubNub, the issue manifests regardless of whether the window.print() function was triggered remotely or not. We faced the same issue whith print() being triggered locally when the user presses a custom Print button on the page. If you can also adapt your answer to the more general case, it will be less confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @Amir you need to unsubscribe from all channels after you issue the `window.print()` command.  then re-subscribe inside of a `setTimeout( fn, 1000 );`.  Make sure to set `restore: true` on resubscribe to receive all messages during the printing process.

Answer (score 1):

## How to Print Remotely with PubNub and JavaScript

With the PubNub Real-time Network, you can signal printers to print remotely on behalf of the user.  **WANRING: This is generally not a good idea and probably very annoying for your users.  We do not recommend you do this.**  However, if you still want to move forward, here is the solution!

```
<script src="https://pubnub.a.ssl.fastly.net/pubnub-3.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script>(function(){

    var channel = "my_channel";
    var pubnub  = PUBNUB.init({
        publish_key   : 'demo',
        subscribe_key : 'demo'
    });

    pubnub.subscribe({ restore: true, channel: channel, message: receive });

    function receive(message) {
        window.print();
        pubnub.unsubscribe({ channel : channel });
        setTimeout( function() { 
            pubnub.subscribe({
                restore : true,
                channel : channel,
                message : receive
            });
        }, 2500 );
    }
})();</script>
```

#### Full Working Example

If you want to see a fully working example: https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/blob/master/examples/print-remote/print.html